# How does HBase internally manages versions?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Lets say an update had happened to a value, it belongs to

```
RowKey 1288,
ColunumFamily cf1
Qualifier  Q1
```

Now one of these values is changed, how does HBase keeps track of this change?

1. Is it via Updates moved into another HFile, fetch all the values and from all the possible HFile for `1288 -> Cf1 -> Q1` with time stamp and respond the latest.
2. Updates are held in the mem store only ? And during Major Compaction the HFiles get renewed with the update logs in mem store ?
3. Any other mechanism ?

Comment: this might help you understand the internals of writes (and reads) a bit better: https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/apache_hbase_internals_locking_and (as stated in the bottom, this is accurate for hbase 0.92)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, when the value is inserted in the first time, HBase will store <1288, cf1, Q1, v1, timestamp, PUT>. If you update v1 to v2, HBase will append a new record <1288, cf1, Q1, v2, timestamp, PUT>. It's in the mem store. If the memstore is full, it will be flushed to the HFile.

When you want to access use <1288, cf1, Q1>, HBase will read all of the versions by scaning the HFiles (Exactly, row key range, timestamp, and bloomfilter in the HFile will help HBase quickly judge if a row key is in some HFile). At last, by default, it will return the latest value to you. In addition, you can ask HBase to return more versions.

If you want to know the mechanism in the HBase, I suggest you read the paper about [bigtable](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf). After that, you can read [HBase: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449396100) CHAPTER 8
Architecture and [The Apache HBase™ Reference Guide](http://hbase.apache.org/book/book.html) Chapter 9. Architecture

Comment: So You mean to say its option 2 ,
Updates are held in the  ** mem store only,** And during **Major Compaction the HFiles get renewed** with the update logs in mem store .

Comment: At first, it will be in memstore. But when the memstore is full, it will be flushed to the HFile. Major Compaction is only used to compact some small HFiles to one big HFile.

Comment: "But when the memstore is full, it will be flushed to the HFile",
So it would be flushed into smaller HFiles ?
Which later would be made big during MajorCompaction ?

Comment: Yes, it's flushed to a small HFile only containing the data in the memstore. You can force HBase to execute a major compaction to combine all of the small HFiles to one large HFile. There is a minor compaction combining several HFiles to a bigger HFile after a certain peroid. Another difference between major compaction and minor compaction is that major compaction will remove the rows which have already deleted.